# Is there a standard way of segregating unit and functional tests for a Symfony2 app?

Tags: php, testing, symfony

I have a Symfony2 app with unit and functional tests, and I wondered whether there was a usual practice to segregate unit and functional tests so that I don't have the overhead of compiling the configuration etc whenever I run the test suite?  A unit test suite shouldn't depend on the presence of a database, or a particular configuration.  I was thinking of adopting a naming pattern to disambiguate functional tests, or to somehow make two different test suites, one excluding the Tests/Controller directory in a bundle, and the other only including that pattern.

Is this a concern shared by anyone else, and what answers have you come to? Does anyone else share my sense that, if possible, unit and functional tests in Symfony2 apps should ideally be segregated by default?

Answer (score 2):

Usually people use different tools for unit and acceptance/functional tests: PHPUnit for the former and [Behat](http://behat.org/) for the latter. With Behat you'll have your tests in the `Features` namespace and will run them with the `app/console -e=test behat` command, while PHPUnit with `phpunit` command. [`FOSCommentBundle`](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSCommentBundle) is an example of this.

If you don't want to use Behat for this, I've seen some people suggesting to use the `Tests` namespace for unit tests and the `Test` namespace for functional ones.

Comment: Thanks for this.  So, Behat is the de facto standard for functional testing in Symfony2 now?  I can start using that instead, but of course it doesn't solve the issue, which is that the standard conventions for storing tests, which may include subclasses of WebTestCase (i.e. functional tests), don't disambiguate between unit and functional.

Comment: If you go with Behat, you'll stop using `WebTestCase` and use Behat & Mink instead for acceptance/functional testing. This way your `Tests` namespace will have unit tests only.

Comment: I get that. :) I just want to know if the community has mostly moved with their feet to using Behat/Mink over `WebTestCase`, because as long as `WebTestCase` is in the framework, and is documented as the way to do functional tests (even if we know you can use a BDD framework as an alternative), and there's no automatic segregation of test suites, this seems broken to me.